# Set the focus on a specified row in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can I get the focus on a specified row in `JTable` i.e if click on first row, first row will get focused, if I click on second row,second row will get focused and so on...

But I need to get the focus on a specified row i.e if I want get the focus on first row, it will only be get focused, the other rows should not be get focus when I clicked on them.

I tried with `getTable().requestFocus()` and `getTable().changeSelection(1, 1, false, false)` methods but it's not working.

Can anyone please help me? I am new to Java Swing.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Comment: *"i am new to java swings"*  That should be "I am new to Java Swing"*  (3 upper case letters and a singular as opposed to plural).

Comment: changeSelection is proper method, rest are in two comment above (by @ Andrew Thompson)

Answer (score 3):

The methods you are looking for are [JTable#setRowSelectionInterval](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionInterval%28int,%20int%29) and [JTable#setColumnSelectionInterval](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setColumnSelectionInterval%28int,%20int%29)